# Why does my Samsung 830 make a loud squeal on write?

Tags: ssd

Anytime I write to my Samsung 830 (256 GB) SSD it emits a rather loud squeal/coil whine.

Any thoughts on what to do besides RMA?

Comment: Thats definately NOT normal behaviour, and you are probably best off getting the drive replaced.

Comment: I have a Corsair force and it's `squealing` with frequency relative to speed of reading/writing (writing is louder). It's annoying but I register that only in silent spaces.

Comment: What answer do you expect other than it being a defect? Unless you go for RMA or some expensive or weird silencing techniques, there isn't much you can do; and I would really prefer the RMA over anything else, because that SSD isn't free and you don't want its breakage to cost you money...

Answer (score 0):

RMA the drive, nothing else you can do other than waiting for it to fail.